# Can Android 2.3.4 be rooted?

Tags: rooting, 2.3-gingerbread

I have a Samsung Mesmerize and I've recently upgraded to my carrier's official release of Android 2.3.4, but to my dismay SuperOneClick doesn't seem to be able to root the device, it's always worked with past versions.

Does Gingerbreak no longer work with 2.3.4? Is there any simple way to root 2.3.4 yet without reflashing and other device changes? I would like to avoid reflashing the device *again* or altering the device from stock significantly if at all possible.

Comment: Take it to your service provider and ask him to format it for you.

Comment: @abhi I'm not sure what you're getting at, the device is already on Android 2.3.4, I'm asking how to root this version, not get updated to this version

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The SuperOneClick dev's website http://shortfuse.org/ states on their [August compatibility list](http://shortfuse.org/?p=94):

> All 2.3.4 devices need a custom root method.

Looking around, there doesn't seem to be a universal one click root method for 2.3.4 yet, most of the root methods for the later Gingerbreads involve flashing custom firmware, etc which is more involved.

Comment: Well darn, that's what I was afraid of. Thanks for the info

Comment: Do you happen to know if ShortFuse is working on getting oneclick to work on 2.3.4?